# Xcode error - unknown type name 'home'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

this is my first question on stackoverflow.! Cheers.!

Please review my code from the link below. I have copy pasted appdelegate.h, appdelegate.m, viewcotroller.h&.m to a text document for reviewing purposes.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/85614p44t8eiqif/HomePageViewController.rtf

I will explain my problem in detail below.

I'm trying to recreate UICatalogue in a smaller scale all through code. I'm an app developement trainee.  This is what I have done so far.

Keep in mind that my knowledge on Xcode and Objective-C is very limited. I'm using Xcode 5.1.1

- I have created an instance variable (HPVC) for the Home Page view controller "HomePageViewController"  in AppDelegate.h
- I have set this HPVC as rootviewcontroller.
- Declared and defined some instance variables.

*But I'm stuck in a loop from what I have searched so far.

I understand the importing has ended up in a loop. But I cant fix it.

Please check this and give me an answer. I can start my project If I can clear this obstacle.

Here is a screenshot of the error

http://www.mediafire.com/view/yjmwbb2dcb7rymd/Error.png

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  NewUICatalogue1
//
//  Created by Roshith Balendran on 18/04/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Roshith Balendran. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HomePageViewController.h"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

{
    HomePageViewController *HPVC;

}


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end





    //
    //  AppDelegate.m
    //  NewUICatalogue1
    //
    //  Created by Roshith Balendran on 18/04/14.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 Roshith Balendran. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "AppDelegate.h"


    @implementation AppDelegate


    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        HPVC=[[HomePageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomePageViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController=HPVC;

        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    @end


    //
    //  HomePageViewController.h
    //  NewUICatalogue1
    //
    //  Created by Roshith Balendran on 18/04/14.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 Roshith Balendran. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface HomePageViewController : UIViewController

    //Background Images for all the Views.
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *HomePageBG;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page1ButtonBG;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page2ControlsBG;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page3TextFieldBG;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page4TextView;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page5Images;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page6Segments;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page7Toolbar;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page8Alerts;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *Page9Transitions;

    //Home Page Elements.
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UILabel *lblHomePageHeader;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UILabel *lblHomePageWelcome;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage1;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage2;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage3;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage4;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage5;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage6;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage7;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage8;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnPage9;
    @property(nonatomic,strong) UIButton *BtnChangeBGColor;





    //Future Update. Add Button to change all button colors in Home Page.

    @end


    //
    //  HomePageViewController.m
    //  NewUICatalogue1
    //
    //  Created by Roshith Balendran on 18/04/14.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 Roshith Balendran. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "HomePageViewController.h"

    @interface HomePageViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation HomePageViewController

    @synthesize HomePageBG;
    @synthesize Page1ButtonBG;
    @synthesize Page2ControlsBG;
    @synthesize Page3TextFieldBG;
    @synthesize Page4TextView;
    @synthesize Page5Images;
    @synthesize Page6Segments;
    @synthesize Page7Toolbar;
    @synthesize Page8Alerts;
    @synthesize Page9Transitions;

    @synthesize lblHomePageHeader;
    @synthesize lblHomePageWelcome;
    @synthesize BtnPage1;
    @synthesize BtnPage2;
    @synthesize BtnPage3;
    @synthesize BtnPage4;
    @synthesize BtnPage5;
    @synthesize BtnPage6;
    @synthesize BtnPage7;
    @synthesize BtnPage8;
    @synthesize BtnPage9;
    @synthesize BtnChangeBGColor;



    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        //Home Page Background image added.
        HomePageBG=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        HomePageBG.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Red"];
        [self.view addSubview:HomePageBG];


    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    #pragma mark - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    @end
```

Comment: don't make us download your code. identify problematic parts and paste them here.

Comment: But the thing is, I don't exactly understand how to put code here. I can paste it only as plain text.
Please buddy, be a little easy. I'm new to stackoverflow. I don't understand what four white space indent means.

Comment: You didn't share the .xib file.

Comment: just paste the code, select it with your mouse, press the source code button. easy enough?

Comment: Just make a new project on Xcode, copy and paste your existing code because there is no error for me.

Comment: Thanx vikingosegundo. That was informative.

Comment: @Winston: I didn't add an xib file, as I was trying to learn how to use code properly. Its an experiment.

Comment: I will try it Winston and let you know.

Comment: Tried it winston, same error.!

Comment: I can send you the project I made if you want.

Comment: Winston, i am trying to understand my mistakes...  It would be nice if some one points out the errors exactly.! But please do send your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything is correct but you forgot to import  #import "HomePageViewController.h" on app delegate.m class